# how to add space in Y axis matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a simple plot in matplotlib. Every time that I plot a data, the graph render an exact Y axis to my plot. What I want is to add some space or allowance on my Y-axis. My maximum value in plot is 5

[image: Graph with Max value 5]

I want my graph to show at least up to 6 or 10 on it's Y-axis.
How ?

Thanks

Comment: By setting certain axis limit, such as `ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 3.5)` and `ax.set_ylim(1.5, 5.5)` you can force the plot to add space.

Comment: can you please identify the parameters that I have to use ? what is that "-05" and "3.5"

Comment: As you want the range of axis to be larger than the supplied range, you have to explicitly pass values smaller and larger that your xdata and ydata min and max to extend the axis. Thats why I gave "-05" and "3.5" which are little smaller and larger than your xdata. Same for ydata. To automate you can also do something like this, `ax.set_xlim(xdata.min()-0.1*xdata.min(), xdata.max()-0.1*xdata.max())`.

Comment: @Ashish: Now I get it. Sorry, I'm new to this library. thanks a lot